# Python function will cycle through but error on the final iteration

Tags: python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy

On the following Python function I am using Python 2.7.6 and SQLAlchemy as the ORM. I am stumped as to why I keep getting the following error even though the function cycles through.

```
def vacantShelter():
#Used to stay in bounds of the all the entries in the DB
shelterCount = session.query(Shelter).count
shelter_id = 1
print "Here are the Shelter results:"
while(shelter_id<=shelterCount):
    shelter = session.query(Shelter).filter(Shelter.id == shelter_id).first()
    if(shelter.max_capacity >= getShelterOccupancy(shelter_id)):
        print shelter.name + " has available space"
    else:
        print shelter.name + " is full! :("
    shelter_id = shelter_id + 1
```

What is confusing me is that it is functioning correctly at first considering there are results, I do not understand why on the last iteration it fails or what to do about it.

```
`Here are the Shelter results:
Oakland Animal Services has available space
San Francisco SPCA Mission Adoption Center is full! :(
Wonder Dog Rescue has available space
Humane Society of Alameda is full! :(
Palo Alto Humane Society is full! :(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pup_test.py", line 82, in vacantShelter
    if(shelter.max_capacity >= getShelterOccupancy(shelter_id)):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'max_capacity'`
```

Comment: Maybe there are *holes* in the `Shelter.id` values? For example, there could be rows with the `id` value of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]`. When you reach the last element, you will try to find a `Shelter` with id of `6`, but it does not exist.

Comment: I added the following code after creating the shelter object and my error is no more:                               `if not shelter:
   return` Thanks for hints @van.                                                                      Is this the most effective move though?

Comment: i will add an answer because of the code samples i would like to show.

Comment: I do not think it is a correct move at all, because your solution will actually *miss* some of the *Shelters* with the highest `id` values.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this error is the presence of *holes* in the `Shelter.id` values. For example, there the table could contain rows with the `id` value of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]`. When you reach the last element, you will try to find a Shelter with id of `6`, but it does not exist.

In principal, the way your code works now is by making a very bold assumption that all rows in the database have consecutive `id` values starting from `1`. But this is generally not the case. Instead, you could directly iterate over the instances, and not load them one-by-one:

```
def vacantShelter():
    shelters = session.query(Shelter).all()
    for shelter in shelters:
        if(shelter.max_capacity >= getShelterOccupancy(shelter.id)):
            print shelter.name + " has available space"
        else:
            print shelter.name + " is full! :("
```

Also, it is much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks @van it makes sense.

Comment: Sure. And if your `getShelterOccupancy(...)` could also be done on the database side, you could potentially execute all the logic in one query